# Magento 2 URL issues

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php, admin, url

I use Magento 2.2.4 version, if I open a subcategories my URL have .html suffix in both: category and subcategory.

The url is look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/en/clothes.html/pants.html
```

and the product

```
https://www.example.com/en/clothes/pants.html/hot-pants.html
```

**How I can made the url for categories to be like this:**

```
https://www.example.com/en/clothes/pants.html
```

and the same for product, to remove the html suffix from url too:

```
https://www.example.com/en/clothes/pants/hot-pants.html
```

My Catalog SEO configuration is:

[image]

If I try to remove the **Catalog URL Suffix** I have the following error:

```
Unique constraint violation found
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To re-generate all Url rewrites of the categories/products in all stores (it support a multi stores) run:

```
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate
```

To regenerate Url rewrites in the specific store view (e.g.: store view id is "2"):

```
php bin/magento ok:urlrewrites:regenerate 2
```

Don't forget to reindexing and flush the cache.

Comment: Hi thank you, I already do this and without success.

Comment: Its showing the error. Did you try enabling that setting at store/website level?

Comment: sorry don't understand very well

Comment: "Use category path for product URL" set to "Yes" at sore level. Try doing it

Comment: is the same like before, nothing change

Comment: Hi, I fix it the rewrite regenerate extension was okay but on my server was some cache app and for that I don't see the changes. Thank you

Comment: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex` did you run

Comment: yes is okay now, I just post a new question here related to registration page, maybe you can help me with that? thank you again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80404/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-robert).